# Change admin panel template

Tags: theming, users, dashboard

I created a custom template and by mistake i chose my template as a adminpanel template.

that got rid of the dashboard. how change the template to default template.

Comment: Delete the custom template file and clear caches maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your-site/admin/appearance page, remove the styles (in Firefox is View/Page Style/No Style) and find the Administration theme form.

Select seven as administration theme and save configuration.